# How to fix side divs and make centre div scrollable using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have following layout:-

[image: Layout]

I was trying to achieve that when I scroll and as soon as side red divs reach the top they become fixed at that position and from there on the green div can be scrolled more(Basically I want to keep my red divs in the frame always).

I used flex to align 3 divs:-

Following is my HTML:-

```
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="left-navbar"></div>
    <div class="content-section"></div>
    <div class="right-navbar"></div>
</div>
```

Following is my css:-

```
.left-navbar,.right-navbar{
    width: 15%; /*change */
    height:10em;
    margin: 20px 30px 0 20px;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
}

.content-container{
    display:flex;/*Add webkit flex properties */
}

.content-section{
    height: 100em;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: green;
}
.stick{
       position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
 }
```

Following is my JS:-

```
function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('.left-navbar').offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('.left-navbar').addClass('stick');
        /* $('#sticky-anchor').height($('#sticky').outerHeight()); */
    } else {
        $('.left-navbar').removeClass('stick');
        /*$('#sticky-anchor').height(0); */
    }
}


$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});
```

So now when i reach the top the left div does get fixed but the center divs moves left and left red div comes over it.[image]

Can someone help me on this? The red divs should be fixed once they reach top and centre div should be scrollable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a codepen showing how this can be done:

http://codepen.io/thecox/pen/OXPZzr

When the navbars become `fixed`, they no longer occupy space on the page. So the `content-section` collapses into the area left by the `left-navbar`. Instead of adding the `sticky` class to the navbars, I added it to the container so multiple elements could be adjusted. I removed the flex behavior, and used standard floats.

```
.content-container.sticky .left-navbar,
.content-container.sticky .right-navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.content-container.sticky .left-navbar {
  left: 0;
}

.content-container.sticky .right-navbar {
  right: 0;
}
```

Finally, to resolve some serious issues with jumpiness, I had the JS code check that it's scrolled beyond the initial container (otherwise, it calculates being at the top of the `left-navbar` over and over). Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: i got the first part, but little confused with JS script, what do u mean by initial container? Are u talking about the content-container here?Also what you mean by over and over?

Comment: Sure thing, let me clarify. Previously, you had the `sticky` class being added to the `left` and `right` navbars on scroll, when the top of the window reached those elements. Since the class being added made those elements `fixed`, it would detect them at the top of the window, thus removing and adding the `sticky` class over and over again, while scrolling. I was referring to the `.content-section` as the initial container, as that's where you actually want to start scrolling the fixed navbars (when the window reaches that container). Let me know if that helps at all!